# Laravel/Vagrant issue

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, vagrant, homestead

I've got a school project and I pushed this to my bitbucket account.
A friend of me needs to pull this project to do some changes and other stuff.

The problem is, whenever he pulls the project and tries to open vagrant, there are no files in his "vagrant ssh".

We tried the 'composer install' for the vendor files.
We got another homestead.yaml file for launching vagrant but it still doesn't seem to fix our problem.

For my part everything works fine, but when my friend pulls the project localy he just can't seem to find any files in his 'vagrant ssh environment'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Homestead.yaml` is there for binding the local storage to the virtual environment. Why doesnt he try to do the `vagrant ssh` first, and then do the pull request inside the shell?

EDIT:

Just try to do things in order. If he followed the instructions for the Laravel installation, his project folder should be something like `C:/Project/PHP/Project_name` and that route should be specified inside the homestead.yaml file like so:

```
folders:
    - map: C:\Project\PHP
      to: /home/vagrant/Code
```

So it says to bind PHP folder on local disk to virtual folder /code in vagrant.
After that create the project folder inside PHP folder, and pull the files inside, and modify the `homestead.yaml` once again to bind the project to browser like so:

```
sites:
    - map: project_name.dev
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/Project_name/public
```

And what is left is to modify hosts file to bind that name to the IP address:

```
192.168.10.10 project_name.dev
```

Comment: If he pulls the project into his ssh, will it be automaticly added into his local machine? I'm fairly new to vagrant ant laravel so sorry if this is kind of a dumb question

Comment: This should do the trick, we're still figuring out how the path works since it's a little different. But we'll find it for sure. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

He should open the Homestead.yaml and check if the "folders" config reflects the mapping of the project on his machine.